# Data e Idioma do computador Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell-script, unix

Existe alguma função em shell script que pegue a data e hora (fuso horário) e idioma que estão configurados no computador?

Comment: Acho que isso pode funcionar: `date +%d/%m/%Y" - "%H:%M:%S`

Answer (score 1):

Isso deveria ser trivial, na verdade:

```
#!/bin/sh

# script /tmp/tes.sh

language=$LANG                    # Idioma
date=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S") # Data e hora local
timezone_offset=$(date +%z)       # Fuso horário
```